# display second paragraph for the matching expression in a text file

Tags: linux, awk, grep, expression, aix

i need a help with grep and awk. Trying to display some text related to a searched expressiion but that text to be displayed is in a separate paragraph.

This is my text format in my text file:

```
Application :
  Address :                0x07000039435882C0
  AppHandl [nod-index] :   52473    [000-52473]
  TranHdl :                132
  Application PID :        0
  Application Node Name :

  IP Address:              8
  Connection Start Time :  (1429703458)Wed Apr 22 07:50:58 2015
  Client User ID :         n/a
  System Auth ID :         MMSCORE
  Coordinator EDU ID :     315757
  Coordinator Partition :  0
  Number of Agents :       1
  Locks timeout value :    NotSet
  Locks Escalation :       No
  Workload ID :            1
  Workload Occurrence ID : 266654
  Trusted Context :        n/a
  Connection Trust Type :  non trusted
  Role Inherited :         n/a
  Application Status :     UOW-Executing
  Application Name :       db2jcc_application
  Application ID :

  TranHdl :                132
  Application PID :        0
  Application Node Name :

  IP Address:

  Connection Start Time :  (1429703458)Wed Apr 22 07:50:58 2015
  Client User ID :         n/a
  System Auth ID :         MMSCORE
  Coordinator EDU ID :     315757
  Coordinator Partition :  0
  Number of Agents :       1
  Locks timeout value :    NotSet
  Locks Escalation :       No
  Workload ID :            1
  Workload Occurrence ID : 266654
  Trusted Context :        n/a
  Connection Trust Type :  non trusted
  Role Inherited :         n/a
  Application Status :     UOW-Executing
  Application Name :       db2jcc_application
  Application ID :         169.83.188.178.49385.150423170149
  ClientUserID :           n/a
  ClientWrkstnName :

  ClientApplName :         n/a
  ClientAccntng :          n/a
  CollectActData:          N
  CollectActPartition:     C
  SectionActuals:          N
```

List of active statements :
   *UOW-ID :          6345
    Activity ID :     2
    Package Schema :  MMSCORE
    Package Name :    P0465265
    Package Version :
    Section Number :  1
    SQL Type :        Static
    Isolation :       CS
    Statement Type :  DML, Select (blockable)

*UOW-ID :          689
    Activity ID :     39
    Package Schema :  PROF
    Package Name :    P366175099
    Package Version :
    Section Number :  35
    SQL Type :        Static
    Isolation :       CS
    Statement Type :  Top-level SET, no SQL

```
UOW-ID :          689
Activity ID :     1
Package Schema :  NULLID
Package Name :    SYSSN300
Package Version :
Section Number :  1
SQL Type :        Dynamic
Isolation :       RS
Statement Type :  CALL
Statement :       call
PKG_FULL_PROFILE_V3.SP_LIST_PROFILE (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

i will be searchibg for AppHandl value which is 52473, once found, i would like to display every paragraph starting with UOW-ID.

In the text file, i will have many entries starting with Application: paragraph as above, so i want only to display all UOW_ID for that specific application handle i am searching.

so the output will look like this based on the text file i pasted above when i search for specific AppHandle:

List of active statements :
   *UOW-ID :          6345
    Activity ID :     2
    Package Schema :  MMSCORE
    Package Name :    P0465265
    Package Version :
    Section Number :  1
    SQL Type :        Static
    Isolation :       CS
    Statement Type :  DML, Select (blockable)

*UOW-ID :          689
    Activity ID :     39
    Package Schema :  PROF
    Package Name :    P366175099
    Package Version :
    Section Number :  35
    SQL Type :        Static
    Isolation :       CS
    Statement Type :  Top-level SET, no SQL

`UOW-ID :          689
Activity ID :     1
Package Schema :  NULLID
Package Name :    SYSSN300
Package Version :
Section Number :  1
SQL Type :        Dynamic
Isolation :       RS
Statement Type :  CALL
Statement :       call
PKG_FULL_PROFILE_V3.SP_LIST_PROFILE (?, ?, ?, ?)`

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by a paragraph in this context. Show the expected output given that input. Should there be a blank line before the 2nd `List of active statements :` line? Make sure your posted sample input is EXACTLY correct.

Comment: no blank line after list of active statements:

Comment: List of active statements :
   *UOW-ID :          689
    Activity ID :     39
    Package Schema :  PROF
    Package Name :    P366175099
    Package Version :
    Section Number :  35
    SQL Type :        Static
    Isolation :       CS
    Statement Type :  Top-level SET, no SQL

    UOW-ID :          689
    Activity ID :     1
    Package Schema :  NULLID
    Package Name :    SYSSN300
    Package Version :
    Section Number :  1
    SQL Type :        Dynamic
    Isolation :       RS
    Statement Type :  CALL
    Statement :       call
    PKG_FULL_PROFILE_V3.SP_LIST_PROFILE (?,

Comment: That is not what I asked. I asked "Should there be a blank line **before** the **2nd** List of active statements". Don't try to put sample input/output or code in a comment as you cannot format it. Edit your question to contain all relevant, accurate information including sample input AND expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this AWK script:

```
{
    if($0 ~ /AppHandl/) {
        if($0 ~ /AppHandl.*52473/) {
            found = 1
        }
        else {
            found = 0
        }
    }

    if(found) {
        if($0 ~ /UOW-ID/) {
            paragraph = 1
            print prev
        }
        if($0 ~ /^$/) {
            paragraph = 0
            printf "\n"
        }
    }
    if(found && paragraph) {
        print
    }
    prev = $0
}
```

After it finds AppHandl value 52473, it prints all paragraphs starting with OUW-ID, until AppHandle with different value is found. That's how I understand your request.

It produces the same output as you requested in your edited question. If you need some cosmetic changes, like different formatting, I hope you are able to modify my example on your own.